# How to make a group of balloons this big?

Tags: modeling, particles

This is what I achieved with a particle system:

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: What's the problem? Looks like you need to increase particle count and make them smaller.

Comment: @Jerryno The balloons at the bottom become too small. They overlap with each other. And I am unable to achieve that huge volume.

Comment: Does [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdNI9BeN1X0) help?